# Attempting to interact with DOM element input with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

My issue is attempting to interact with a website using VBA.

I have dealt with filling in input boxes by simply saying `ie.document.getElementById(strId).value = my_value` as well as when those elements exist inside of a form.

But for the life of me I cannot get this to work. I will post as much of the HTML as I can.

HTML:

```
<input title="Order Number" class="mtn-srch-text text-field req" id="orderNum" type="text" maxLength="10" data-sticky-placeholder="Order Number">
```

VBA that is attempting to take the orderNum field and fill it in.

```
 objBrowser.document.getElementById("orderNum").value = "1234"
```

Object Required error each time, so I am thinking its not looking in the right spot as the element surely exists, but I am incorrectly pointing to it. Since I do not see any form tags in the HTML on this page, I did not know how to proceed to drill down to get this input box filled. Any advice would be awesome!

Adding some more of the code, had to remove a few of the URLS and username/pass but as you can see navigating is very simply until we get to the iFrames part of it. Which I now see each iFrame has a differebt SRC which is probably why

```
 .contentDocument.getelementbyId("textbox").value = "test"
```

wont work. What we are focused on is everything below the dotted line, as you can see its just me toying around stepping through an attempting different things.

```
   Dim strPosUrl As String, strUsername As String, strPassword As String, _
       strStoreDomId As String, strStore As String, _
       strBtnStoreUpdateDomId As String, strOrder As String, _
       strLoadingSpinner As String, strCssAttributeSpinner As String, _
       strCssTextSpinner As String
    Dim objBrowser As Object 'SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim blnSsoLogin As Boolean
    Dim intStoreColNum As Integer, intOrderColNum As Integer, _
        intCreditCardColNum As Integer
    'Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

            'these are test vars-----------------
            strStore = "Data"
            strOrder = "Data"
            '----------------------------------
            strLoadingSpinner = "spinnerUnique"
            strCssAttributeSpinner = "style"
            strCssTextSpinner = "display: none;"

            strUsername = "example"
            strPassword = "EXample"
            strStoreDomId = "orderLocInputId"
            strBtnStoreUpdateDomId = "orderLocValueUpdate"
            strPosUrl = "https://example.jsp"

            Set objBrowser = New InternetExplorerMedium
            objBrowser.Visible = True
            browserNavigate strPosUrl, objBrowser
            browserWait objBrowser
            blnSsoLogin = ssoLoginCheck(objBrowser)

            Select Case blnSsoLogin

                    Case Is = True
                            ssoLoginMod strUsername, strPassword, objBrowser
                            browserWait objBrowser
                    Case Is = False

            End Select

            fillTextboxWithId objBrowser, strStoreDomId, strStore
            clickButtonWithId objBrowser, strBtnStoreUpdateDomId
            browserWait objBrowser

            foundOrNot strLoadingSpinner, strCssAttributeSpinner, _
                       strCssTextSpinner, objBrowser



'-----------------------------------------------------
            Dim IFrameText As Object
            Set IFrameText = objBrowser.document.getElementById("frmHome")
            IFrameText.HTML.getElementById("ordernum").Value = "1223"

            Dim x As String
            objBrowser.navigate "https://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com" & x
            x = objBrowser.LocationURL

            x = "just messing with stuff"

            Set IFrameText = objBrowser.document.getElementById("frmHome")
            Dim elem As Object
           For Each elem In IFrameText
                If elem.innerText Like "*true*" Then
                MsgBox (elem)
                End If
                Next
```

Comment: Is the input in a frame?  If you put a break just before you try to access the element and wait a couple of seconds before continuing does it then work?

Comment: Hi, I think I see where you are going. I have gotten pretty good about making sure items I require on a page are all loaded before I try to access anything. But I did attempt what you said, but no luck, same thing.

Comment: Id like to note I use the java script spinner css text to let me know when a page is done loading, I find this works great for pages that are running scripts even after IE stops loading.

Comment: Can't really offer any more suggestions without a URL.

Comment: Unfortunately, you would not be able to access the URL. What I can do is show this.

Comment: <iframe title="Home Frame" class="main" id="frmHome" src="/retail/xxxxx=home"></iframe>    I am then able to have an object the references that iframe as printing it shows (htlmIframeElement), but then the usual objFrm.getelementbyid("myID").value = "test" gives the object required, also would like to add, any text field outside of this iFrame can easily be accessed with the getElementById without anything else.

Comment: It would help to add more of your code to your question: there's only a single line right now.

Comment: added a bit more, evidently I don't know how to properly put it in so that stack could understand the top part was DIM statements :( sorry

Comment: Try: `IFrameText.document.getElementById("ordernum").Value = "1223"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was in a table.

So its really simple:

```
getelementbyid("yourTableId").getElementsByTagName("tr")(x row).getElementsByTagName("td")(x cell)
```

After that, do what you want with the element.